# How to use react-table to put object (json dict) key/value pairs on rows and not put keys on columns

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, react-table

I am pretty new to react, but am trying to do the following ...

Am making API requests to ElasticSearch (using elasticsearch npm package) from reactjs.
I want to put some of the returned json data (after putting in Objects and distilling keys/values) into a table using the react-table package ...

AFAI understand most examples on the react-table documentation talk about mapping object keys to columns and then using the column accessors to populate the values (from key/values) in the correct columns as rows. So, map objects keys to columns and put values in as rows ...

But in my case I want to put values AND keys into rows and have a few manually defined columns ...
At this point there is no proper mapping between columnn accessors and object keys ...

Is ther ea way to do this using react-table? WOuld appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction reagrding documentation/examples ...

Also, my returend JSON data has some nested dicts ...

See example dataset below

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "obj-model",
        ...
        "_source" : {
          "MoClass" : {
            "Name" : "fvBD",
            "Description" : "A bridge domain is a unique l2 forwarding domain that contains one or more subnets. Each bridge domain must be linked to a context.",
            "Class ID" : "1887",
            "Class Label" : "Bridge Domain",
            "AbstractionLayer" : "Logical Model",
            "Write Access" : "[admin, tenant-connectivity-l2]",
            "Read Access" : "[access-connectivity-l3, admin, fabric-connectivity-l3, nw-svc-device, nw-svc-policy, tenant-connectivity-l2, tenant-connectivity-l3, tenant-connectivity-mgmt, tenant-epg, tenant-ext-connectivity-l2, tenant-ext-connectivity-l3, tenant-ext-protocol-l3, tenant-network-profile, tenant-protocol-l2, tenant-protocol-l3, tenant-security]",
            "Semantic Scope" : "EPG",
            "Semantic Scope Evaluation Rule" : "Explicit",
            "Monitoring Policy Source" : "Explicit",
              "Property" : [    <===================== NESTED DICT
              {
                "Name" : "OptimizeWanBandwidth",
                "Comment" : "OptimizeWanBandwidth flag is enabled between sites",
                "Constants" : [
                  "no",
                  "yes"
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name" : "annotation",
                "Comment" : "NO COMMENTS",
                "Constants" : [
                  "no",
                  "yes"
                ]
              },
              ...
```

Comment: Is this Nested dict is going to be your row data?

Comment: @Sabit Rakhim, both the parent dict and nested dict will be row data